# How to add text "Please wait a while..." on clicking the button in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I had created some function calls using JavaScript and made it delay 7 seconds now I want that when a user clicks the button, a "please wait..." text(not in the button text) appears as soon as the delay time starts.

"Please wait" text should appear as headline tag(h3 or h4 tag)

Any help/suggestion, please...

```js
function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  console.log("clicked on Test-Button");
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button onclick="setTimeout(yes, 7000)">Test</button> <!-- timeout -->
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Your click sets a 7s timeout, so, nothing will happen before 7s. You need to trigger a function that does immediately what you want to be done immediately, _and_ also triggers a 7s timeout for future actions.

Comment: You *can* put any amount of javascript in the `onclick=` - left this as a comment rather than an answer as using `onclick=` is outdated practice.   eg `<button onclick='myFunc();$("#wait").text("wait...");setTimeout(yes, 7000)`>`  - it's hard to read, hard to maintain and easy to get lost.   Use js to set the events for clearer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to attach eventListeners via javascript (instead of the inline `onclick`) - and in this case, it affords us a lovely opportunity to do the Please Wait... insertion - which gets overwritten (desirably) when the finished output arrives.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()  => {
  document.querySelector('button.test-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = '<h3>Please Wait...</h3>';
    setTimeout(yes, 7000)
  })
})

function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button class='test-btn'>Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: It is weird to see that this code is not working in HTML5 format. please look into this

Comment: @ASHISHKUMAR - I did test in a HTML5 page and it was fine. I think perhaps the issue is script over html -- I have revised my answer using a window.onload block. That should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Move the setTimeout to inside the click

I also suggest addEventListener to not have inline event handlers

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked on Test-Button");
    const wait = document.getElementById('wait');
    wait.removeAttribute("hidden")
    setTimeout(function() {
      const name = document.getElementById('name'),
        age = document.getElementById('age'),
        str = '<p>Hello!<br/>My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You ' + name.value + '?</p>';
      wait.setAttribute("hidden", true)
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
    }, 7000);
  });
});
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button type="button" id="test">Test</button>
<!-- timeout --><span id="wait" hidden>Please wait</span>
<p id="test"></p>
```